# Pass a memory address by register

Tags: assembly, stack, parameter-passing, 68000, easy68k

How do I pass a memory address from a register to other? My following routine receive the string memory address from stack (yes, it's necessary) and then try to put into `D1` registers but it doesn't work and [**EASy68k**](http://www.easy68k.com/) emulator crash (or goes in an infinite loop?) when I try run this.

Code:

```
START ORG $1000


    MOVE.L T,D0
    MOVE.L D0,-(SP)
    BSR PRINTS



PRINTS:       
        MOVE.L D0,(SP)+
        MOVE.W D0,A1
        MOVE #14,D0
        TRAP #15
        RTS

T DC.B 'HELLO',0
    END START
```

**UPDATE:** I updated the way as arguments are pushed and poped from stack. Changed to use `PEA` instruction that looks like do exactly what I want to but it still doesn't work.

```
START ORG $1000
        PEA T(PC)
        *MOVE.L D0,-(SP)
        BSR PRINTS
        ADDQ.L #4,SP

    MOVE #9,D0       
        TRAP #15 

PRINTS:        
        MOVE 4(SP),A1
        MOVE #14,D0
        TRAP #15
        RTS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the argument onto the stack correctly, you either need to do:

```
    LEA    T,  A0
    MOVE.L A0, D0
    MOVE.L D0, -(SP)
```

or

```
    PEA.L  T
```

To get the argument *off* the stack correctly, you don't actually want to pop it in the called function.  That's because `BSR` pushes a return address.  Instead, you need to use indexed addressing as follows:

```
    MOVE.L (4,SP), A1  ; read argument from stack, overlooking return address
```

And then to top it off, you need to "pop" the argument from the stack in the *caller* (not the callee), by adding this after the `BSR` instruction:

```
    ADDA.L #4, SP      ; remove argument from stack.
```

The resulting program (which I did test in EASy68K), looks like this:

```
        ORG    $1000
START:  
        PEA.L  T           ; push argument to stack
        BSR    PRINTS      ; call PRINTS; also pushes return address on stack
        ADDA.L #4, SP      ; remove argument from stack.
        SIMHALT

PRINTS:
        MOVE.L (4,SP), A1  ; read argument from stack, overlooking return address
        MOVE.L #14, D0
        TRAP   #15
        RTS

T       DC.B   'HELLO', 0

        END    START        ; last line of source
```

And don't forget that `SIMHALT` ahead of `PRINTS`.  You don't want to fall from your main code into your subroutines.

Oh, and as you've likely discovered:

```
        PEA.L  T(PC)
```

does work in place of

```
        PEA.L  T
```

The main difference is code size.  The first one uses PC-relative addressing to generate the address, while the second stores the full 32-bit address in the object code.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I fixed this but it looks like be half of the problem. It's still not working.

Comment: Shouldn't `MOVE.L T,D0` be `LEA T,D0`?  You want the address of `T`, not the contents of `T`.

Comment: The move will work in the same way as current code. The `LEA T,D0` returns an error: `ERROR: Invalid addressing mode`

Comment: I checked out the manual for make sure. The `LEA` instruction only works for `AN` registers.

Comment: I apologize that my 68K was rusty.  I downloaded EASy68K and edited my answer above appropriately.